# My Update manager not update in debian

Tags: linux, debian

I am new body in Linux Debian , i succeeded to install it but when i ant to make an update i get this error

http://s14.postimage.org/fiiqpow9d/Screenshot.png

any help i will be thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have your sources not properly configured. You can add this:

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-proposed-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
```

To your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove those that are giving you trouble.